# Why is this visited <a> anchor always purple?

Tags: css, html

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Make all anchors and variations plain black text color */
            a,
            a:link,
            a:hover,
            a:focus,
            a:active,
            a:selected,
            a:visited
            {
                color:#000000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#">This is a visited link that is puple</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I visit this page, and click on the link, the text color is purple like the default color of a visited link. How can this be? How can I make the `<a>` text black in all circumstances?

This reproduces in Chrome and IE9; haven't bothered to test anything else yet.

Comment: `a { color: #000; }` is enough

Comment: You don't need to do that override. Just use `a { color: black; }`. If you don't, it'll *really* annoy you in the future. (Nonsense, like `p a` not applying a `color`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove `a:selected` from your css definition. That fixed it for me. Never heard of `:selected`. Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: Heh that's what I get for copy/pasting random code around the web. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe you saw `.selected` which is often used in menus where a "selected" item gets the class "selected". But if you only copied, the random code was wrong ;)

Comment: You're probably right about `.selected` vs. `:selected`. For how sensitive CSS can be (for ex. leaving a trailing comma after the last selector), I'm surprised CSS syntax errors are not presented more blatantly. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: `:selected` was once (over ten years ago) used as a pseudo-class for a checked checkbox or radio button, then changed to `:checked`. Copying code often causes dated code to be copied. Using http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ would have revealed this error.

Answer (score 5):

Because `a:selected` doesn't exist. Remove it!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the a:selected, seems to fix it.  Not sure why as that is a valid option on the anchor tag.

Correction: a:selected isn't valid but a.selected is of course valid. Sorry about that, but either way removing a:selected will fix the issue.

[Fiddler Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rhoenig/G3HHd/1/)